# @yield and @section is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello every body I am trying to use @yield and @section in my project, but it is not working. I am going to show you my code given please help me. I have two views. first one is design.blade.php containing the code

```
@extends('contact')

@section('content')
Hello This is Design called in contact page

@endsection
```

and the second one is contact.blade.php containing the code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">@yield('content')</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me why it is not calling while I am trying to call contact page in browser. It shows an empty or black page.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel (v5.7.0)

Comment: how did you render the view?

Comment: through cmd I see the version of laravel which is (v5.7.0) but the page is showing blank while I am running it on browser because @yield and  is not working

Comment: "_blank page_" meaning no source code? Have you tried viewing the source to see if `contact.blade.php` gets rendered? Have you checked `storage/logs/laravel.log` to see if there are any errors?

Comment: how I can check storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: It's a text file, you open it with your favorite editor.

Comment: It have a large code, how I can found error?

Comment: I see you have some question answered that solved your problem. Quick reminder that you can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to give credit to the user solving your problem and also for others to see how to solve it.

Comment: "_It have a large code, how I can found error?_" Basic log file navigation. Log entries are added at the bottom of the file. There are entries starting with a date (`[2018-03-23 09:32:15]`) anything below that until the next date belongs to an error/warning.

Comment: #54 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MySite\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 {main}
"}

Comment: last sentence in the logs file

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action you should return

```
return view("design");
```

Comment: and the function should be contact or design?

Comment: it should be the one called by your route ie. if your route is Route::get('/contact', 'ExampleController@contact') then it should be contact function

Comment: The code of HomeController.php is <?php



class HomeController extends Controller
{
    //homepage
    public function homepage(){
    return view('homepage');
    }
//Subject Page
  
    public function subject(){
    return view('subject');
    }
   
  
} and the code of contact.blade.php is<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">  @include('content') </h1>
</body>
</html> and the code of design.blade.php is@extends('contact')

@section('content')
Hello This is Design 

@endsection

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, hard to read. Since this is relevant to your question, please [edit] your question and paste the code there, so other users don't have to wade through the comments to get that information. Thanks